# How to disable “Last failed login” message on Centos?

Tags: centos, login, banner

How can I disable the message below when a specific user logs into a Centos machine from console?

```
Last failed login: Sun Jun 30 22:32:35 EST 2018 from 192.168.142.71 on ssh:notty
There were 3 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
```

Note: the user is non-root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming CentOS 7.

```
~# cat /etc/pam.d/postlogin 
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.

session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service !~ gdm* service !~ su* quiet
session     [default=1]   pam_lastlog.so nowtmp showfailed
session     optional      pam_lastlog.so silent noupdate showfailed
```

Here `showfailed` option is responsible for the message about failed logins.

Note: On my machine authconfig is not installed by default, so I'm not too worried about changes being destroyed.

Simply removing this option will disable the message for all users. AFAIK per-user PAM configuration is kinda silly, this is what I came up with:

```
# cat /etc/pam.d/postlogin 
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.

session     [success=ignore default=3] pam_succeed_if.so user in that_non_root_user
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service !~ gdm* service !~ su* quiet
session     [default=4]   pam_lastlog.so nowtmp
session     [default=3]   pam_lastlog.so silent noupdate
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service !~ gdm* service !~ su* quiet
session     [default=1]   pam_lastlog.so nowtmp showfailed
session     optional      pam_lastlog.so silent noupdate showfailed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mikst. Is there any problem to remove authconfig? As it says "User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run".

Comment: AFAIK, authconfig is like NetworkManager for credentials, it's an additional tool that can help setup things for you. I believe it is used by installer, but not installed on the system itself by default. So unless you or someone else installed it, there shouldn't be a problem.